# Why is a regular for loop preferred to forEach?

Tags: kotlin

From [Kotlin's Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html):

> Prefer using higher-order functions (filter, map etc.) to loops. Exception: forEach (prefer using a regular for loop instead, unless the receiver of forEach is nullable or forEach is used as part of a longer call chain).

Why is that? Why should I use:

```
val evenDigits = intArrayOf(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
for (digit in evenDigits)
    println(digit)
```

Instead of:

```
intArrayOf(0, 2, 4, 6, 8).forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: Efficiency, I'd guess?

Comment: Google it before asking. https://blog.gouline.net/kotlin-bits-for-loops-vs-foreach-30548d7472a5

Answer (score 3):

From performance and efficiency perspective `for` is sometimes a bit faster, as using `forEach` might create some additional object/objects in some cases, but this isn't noticeable.

Only difference I could notice is that when using `forEach` you don't have `break` to exit out of loop, there is probably some other way to implement it but I don't think that would as much readable and might be confusing.

Behavior of `continue` can be achieved by using `return@forEach` but again this doesn't state clearly what you are actually doing, while `continue` does, especially if person that is reading code isn't kotlin expert.